# HT index RSI value at end of each month in an xts time series object

Tags: r, xts

First I read-in a csv and create an xts object.

```
require(quantmod)

sugar  <- as.xts(read.zoo("SUGAR.CSV", sep=",", format ="%m/%d/%Y", header=TRUE))
```

Then I create a new series of RSI values using TTR (loads with quantmod)

```
sugarRSI <- RSI(sugar)
```

Now I'd like to get a new series that only includes the value of the last day of each month. There is a last() function in xts, but not clear on how to deploy it efficiently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `apply.monthly(sugarRSI, last)` will do what you want.

Comment: Works like a charm. I need a method of keeping track of all these functions. Thanks much.

Comment: Reading the documentation is possible last step of desperation.  *Seriously*, the zoo vignettes are excellent and almost everything carries over to `xts`.